# I am trying to setup auditing in Mongod

Tags: mongodb, audit

I am bit confused on how to setup enable auditing in mongod enterprise. I went to their website https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-auditing/

I have tired multiple times to output the auditing files to BSON file. I have created a folder called auditLog.bson

Comment: Are you running MongoDB Enterprise, or the community edition?

Comment: The Enterprise version

Comment: If you have purchased MongoDB Enterprise, you have access to support.